# should distribution of predicted probability correspond to training data?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

Say I have classification problem with imbalance training label:
1: 1000
0: 100000

When I train a classifier, like Logistic Regression or Random Forest or XGBoost, it can output predicted probability. Will the mean of all predicted probability be close to mean of training label, which is 0.01 in this case? It seems to me MLE will give such kind of estimation.

Answer (score 1):

no, the predicted probability for most of the models you mentioned is predicting the probability of $y$ given some $x$, or $p(y|x)$ these types of models are known as discriminative models. These types of models model the relationship between $x$ and $y$, not the prior probability of observing $y$

Comment: But OP seems to be asking about $$p(y) \stackrel{?}{\approx} \frac{1}{N} \sum_i^N f(y|x;\theta)$$ for some discriminative model $f$, not about the predicted probability of any single $x$.

Comment: exactly like shimao mentioned. I understand that for single point p(y) is different than p(y|x). But I am not sure if MLE will make mean of predicted probability to close to original mean.